# What do You Call Two Siblings That Are Born on The Same Day, But Different Years?

Tags: meaning

My brother and I were both born on March 18, but he was born in 2000, and I was born in 2002. What do you call that?

Comment: .A coincidence.

Comment: Siblings, I think.